# turning left modules into right modules over bialgebroids

Tags: hopf-algebras, bialgebras

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a left R-bialgebroid as defined in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.3597.pdf on page 87. Let $M$ be a left $\mathcal{B}$-module. Can $M$ be made a right $\mathcal{B}$-module (as for the Hopf algebras, it can be done using the antipode)?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the question is not completely well-posed, but let me try to give an answer anyway.

In general, no, you cannot: there is no "natural" way to convert left modules into right modules. A first vague idea of why this is the case is given by the facts that any ordinary bialgebra over a field $\Bbbk$ is a particular example of a $\Bbbk$-bialgebroid (and we know that for general bialgebras is not necessarily true) and that to speak about *modules* you are only using the *algebra* structure of the bialgebroid, whence you are essentially asking if given an algebra over a commutative ring you may convert actions on one side into actions on the other.

The key fact when doing this over a Hopf algebra is the fact that the antipode is an anti-homomorphism of algebras, but you indeed don't need really an antipode to convert left (resp. right) modules into right (resp. left) ones: an antimultiplicative and unital map would be more than enough.

So, let me sum up a bit. In general, there is no natural way to switch the side of an action, however

- You can, of course, define a new action on the right and make of a left module a bimodule (and hence, in particular, a right module), but this is not necessarily connected with the original left action.
- If your bialgebroid $B$ (and in general any algebra) is endowed with an anti-multiplicative and unital endomorphism $f:B^{op}\to B$, you can use the restriction of scalars to convert any left $B$-module into a left $B^{op}$-module (i.e. a right $B$-module) and viceversa.
- If your bialgebroid $B$ (and in general any algebra) is commutative, then $\mathsf{Id}_B$ is an anti-multiplicative and unital endomorphism and you may apply the previous construction.

This is of course not exhaustive at all, but I hope it answers your question.